# tabular data from pivot xml query oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot-table

I have following Oracle sql query written using "pivot xml" clause

```
SELECT *
   FROM
  (SELECT tid,item,
    current_value
  FROM
    (SELECT rownum,
     last_value(tid ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) tid,
      last_value(category ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) category,
      last_value(item ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) item,
      current_value
    FROM pi_perfdata_new
    ORDER BY rownum
    )
  WHERE category IN ('ClassA','ClassB') and tid is not null
  ) pivot xml (max(current_value) FOR item IN (any ));
```

This gives output in following format:

```
TID  ITEM_XML 

101 <PivotSet><item><column name = "ITEM">MID</column><column name = "MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">C009</column></item><item><column name = "ITEM">PNAME</column><column name = "MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">XYZ CO.</column></item></PivotSet>
102 <PivotSet><item><column name = "ITEM">MID</column><column name = "MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">C011</column></item><item><column name = "ITEM">PNAME</column><column name = "MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">LMN CO.</column></item></PivotSet>
```

Now I need to convert the above XML data in tabular format below:

```
MID   PNAME
c009  XYZ CO. 
c011  LMN CO.
```

I tried something like below but that doesnot gives me desired o/p as above

```
  WITH pivot_info AS  (SELECT *   FROM   (SELECT tid,   item,  current_value
FROM
  (SELECT rownum,
    last_value(tid ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) tid,
    last_value(category ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) category,
    last_value(item ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) item,
    current_value
  FROM pi_perfdata_new
  ORDER BY rownum
  )
WHERE category                           IN ('ClassA','ClassB')
AND tid                                  IS NOT NULL
) pivot xml (MAX(current_value) FOR item IN (ANY ))  ) SELECT extractvalue (value (t), '/item/column[1]') item ,  extractvalue (value (t), '/item/column[2]') value FROM pivot_info,  XMLTable ('/PivotSet/item' passing item_xml) t ;
```

---Above sql gives o/p in following format

```
item value
MID   C009
PNAME XYZ CO.
MID   C011
PNAME LMN CO.
```

But I need data in following tabular format;

```
MID   PNAME
c009  XYZ CO. 
c011  LMN CO.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Please add more tags to your question.